# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"GET" | "get" | …'

Tags: typescript, axios, typescript-typings

I've got a custom hook that uses the `axios` library to perform some requests:

```
const useCustomHook = ({ endPoint = "", method = "GET", options = {} }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);


  const [request, setRequest] = useState<AxiosRequestConfig>({
    url: endPoint,
    method,
    headers: {},
    data: options
  });

{...}
}
```

I bring the Axios types (AxiosRequestConfig) that declare `method` to be of type `Method`:

```
type Method =
  | 'get' | 'GET'
  | 'delete' | 'DELETE'
  | 'head' | 'HEAD'
  | 'options' | 'OPTIONS'
  | 'post' | 'POST'
  | 'put' | 'PUT'
  | 'patch' | 'PATCH'
```

Unfortunately, `method` highlights the below error:
`Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"GET" | "get" | "delete" | "DELETE" | "head" | "HEAD" | "options" | "OPTIONS" | "post" | "POST" | "put" | "PUT" | "patch" | "PATCH" | undefined'.`

[image: code error]

I can always type `method` as `string` but that would break the type safety I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can always type `method` as `string` but that would break the type safety I'm looking for.

`method` should be of type `Method` from `axios`, not `string`:

```
interface CustomHookParam {
    endPoint?: string;
    method?:   Method; // <=== type is `Method` from `axios`'s types
    options?:  SomeAppropriateTypeForTheOptions;
}
const useCustomHook = ({ endPoint = "", method = "GET", options = {} }: CustomHookParam) => {
```

Since they all have defaults, you may want to default the overall parameter as well:

```
const useCustomHook = ({ endPoint = "", method = "GET", options = {} }: CustomHookParam = {}) => {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
```

[On the playground](http:////%20Stand-in%20for%20the%20type%20from%20axios%20type%20Method%20=%20%22GET%22%20%7C%20%22POST%22%20/*%20%7C%20...%20*/;%20%20//%20Stand-in%20for%20whatever%20type%20you%20want%20%60options%60%20to%20have%20type%20SomeAppropriateTypeForTheOptions%20=%20object;%20%20interface%20CustomHookParam%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20endPoint?:%20string;%20%20%20%20%20method?:%20%20%20Method;%20//%20%3C===%20type%20is%20%60Method%60%20from%20%60axios%60's%20types%20%20%20%20%20options?:%20%20SomeAppropriateTypeForTheOptions;%20%7D%20%20const%20useCustomHook%20=%20(%7B%20endPoint%20=%20%22%22,%20method%20=%20%22GET%22,%20options%20=%20%7B%7D%20%7D:%20CustomHookParam%20=%20%7B%7D)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20//%20...implementation...%20%7D;)

Answer (score 3):

I had to declare a variable method with type Method and included that in the request.

```
let method: Method = 'POST';
const request = {
     ...
     method: method
     ...
}
```

The ... is just other unrelated variables to the question.

Answer (score 0):

We can also take an advantage of enum here.

```
enum RequestMethods {
  GET='GET',
  POST='POST',
  PUT='PUT',
  DELETE='DELETE',
}

interface IRequestConfig {
  ...
  method: RequestMethods.GET | RequestMethods.POST | RequestMethods.PUT | RequestMethods.DELETE,
  ...
}

const request: IRequestConfig = {
  ...
  method: RequestMethods.GET,
  ...
}
```